# I need PDF file print in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need PDF file print in to server side using asp.net C# code,
If is possible?

If is it possible mean how to print the PDF file in server side

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/).